# Tags suggestion: e-Ink e-Paper

Tags: feature-request

For questions like this: [Can PaPiRus serve as normal display for Raspberry Pi? (ePaper / eInk Screen HAT)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/44770/359)
linke:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/e-ink/info
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/e-ink/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created the eink tag. Tags are site specific. As a result the tag will not be available on electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I hope it's not *eink* ;)